# Set character set and convert to utf-8 without bom

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

When I using `$file = fopen($destination,'r');` to read file everything works correctly but if my file have cyrillic, greek etc. letters then the letters are like that **ÎŸÎ½Î¿Î¼Î¬Î¶Î¿Î¼Î±Î¹ ÎŒÎ»Î¹Î²ÎµÏ ÎšÎ¿Ï…Î¯Î½**. In Notepad++ you can do that by going `Encoding-->Character Sets-->Greek-->Windows-1253` and then `Encoding-->Convert to UTF-8 without BOM`. How I can do that in php?

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/), [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP does not have any concept of character encodings; strings are binary data. The trick that makes everything seem to work is setting the output device, whether it's a web page or a terminal, to the correct character encoding.

If you are generating a web page, you can send the content-type header to tell the browser how the page is encoded.

```
header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
```